# Mule xml transformation

Tags: xml, mule

In Mule, I'm trying to change a flat file to XML using Datamapper. I have imported the schema as well. But the output payload for this DataMapper is in some stream of bytes. eg: org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [B@14eee304.
Then, I created a file outbound endpoint and then the file generated by the process is in a valid xml format. Can anyone suggest how is this happening?

Comment: Pls show your full Mule config ..

Comment: <flow name="xmltransformerFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\Inbound" connector-ref="File" pollingFrequency="100000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_XML" doc:name="CSV To XML"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\Outbound" outputPattern=".txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the default behaviour of DataMapper to output a byte array whenever it tries to Map an input object to XML. The file outbound endpoint is then able to read this byte array and write it to a file.

What is it that you're after? What you're mentioning is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the point. Ok, lets consider the case of Web service consumer component. The output of the Datamapper which is an XML is the request for a webservice. If the Output for the Datamapper is in bytes. How can i create a valid request with that?

Comment: This is the flow,   <flow name="soap_projectFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\Inbound" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="XML_To_Xml_GetGeoIP_" doc:name="XML To Xml&lt;GetGeoIP&gt;"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="GetGeoIP" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
     /flow>

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with that flow. The Web Service Consumer is able to take in this byte array and send it off as a request to the SOAP web service. Infact, the easiest way to build a SOAP request for the Web Service Consumer is by using the DataMapper transformer.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when running your flow?

Comment: After debugging, the 1st warning is like "Issue in component [XML WRITER:EXT_XML_WRITER0]
 Invalid mapping (Port binding to a root element may produce invalid XML file. Set 'Records per file' or 'Max number of records' component attributes to '1'.)". After execution, the error is  ""Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]""

Comment: That first warning is a known issue with DataMapper and has persisted through a number of Mule versions. Unfortunately it hasn't been fixed yet but chances are it is not the reason why you're getting the exception. Are you positive that the XML that Datamapper is generating is correct? (i.e. does the same request work with other SOAP WS clients such as SoapUI?)

Comment: Yes, I tried with SOAP UI and the response is good. No issues in there.

Comment: I think it's a problem in the ws consumer configuration. It's ok to have a byte[] after datamapper, but you could add an "Object to String" transformer after datamapper in order to get the resulting string and log it for debug purposes. Could you share the ws consumer config please? Regards, Marcos.